# работа с массивом через foreach

Tags: php

Стоит задача вывести из БД таблицу с заголовком. Для отображения заголовка использую foreach, но если использовать такой код:

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
   echo "<td>";
   echo $key;
   echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Происходит задвоение заголовка 0 имя_поля_0 1 имя_поля_1 2 имя_поля_2.
попробовал вывести такой код

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$key} => {$value}" . "<br />";
}
echo "</tr>";

Результат будет
0=> значение_0
имя_поля_0 => значение_0
1=> значение_1
имя_поля_1 => значение_1
2=> значение_2
имя_поля_2 => значение_2
3=> значение_3
имя_поля_3 => значение_3
```

как сделать, чтобы выводился только ключ ассоциативного массива или только индексы?

Comment: В `fetch` методе нужно параметр указать.

Comment: покажите в каком виде $row.

Comment: $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH); у меня подключение к oracle

Comment: использовать OCI_ASSOC???

Comment: Можно увидеть входные данные? Что вы получаете и что вы хотите вывести

Answer (score 4):

В формировании переменной $row
`$row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH);`
Использовал режим `OCI_BOTH`, что означает использование ассоциативного и числового массива.
Необходимо использовать `OCI_ASSOC` или `OCI_NUM`.

Всем спасибо, помогли разобраться, натолкнули на мысль.

Comment: Ваш ответ исправляет причину, остальные ответы - следствия, я думаю вам надо свой ответ принять.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет об обычной нумерации полей, то можно было воспользоваться и обычным инкрементом. Например, следующим образом:

```
<tr>
<? 
$i = 0;
foreach ($row as $value) {
  $i++; 
  ?><td><span id="<?=$value.$i;?>"><?=$i;?></span></td><?
}?>
</tr>
```

Если прямо важно, чтобы были значения ассоциативного массива, то для начала проверить везде ли у пунктов массива есть ключи? Если их нет, то и нет смысла заморачиваться, хотя совет по поводу режима OCI_BOTH тут кстати.

И следи за стилем. Стиль кода ужасен. Почему эти echo и в них голимый html? Почитай инфу по стилю кодирования....

Comment: По стилистике замечание принято! Учимся, набираемся опыта, пока просто понимание логики работы и синтаксиса . Делаю, как проще, пока!

Answer (score -2):

Если нельзя повлиять на данные в $row то так:

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if(is_numeric($key)){ // - для чисел 
    // if(!is_numeric($key)){ // - для не чисел
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
```